# Replace strings with translations from reference table

Tags: c#, string, replace, translate

I'm trying to pull some info off of a korean website and then make those korean characters usable and then put the info in a text file or the like. My idea was to create kind of a reference table (that would be done quickly, as there aren't too many sets of data that need that treatment, roughly 200).

My question is now,
first: if that is actually a solid idea or if there's a better or easier solution,
second: what format would I wanna use for such a table/sheet? csv, xml?

So far I'm getting the info via HtmlAgilityPacks XML/HTML stuff, which works quite well. Any help is appreciated, if you need any of my code, let me know so I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

`.csv` read slightly faster than `.txt`. But if only 200 characters, I think the difference is insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a resource file, normally used for exactly what you are doing and the appropriate translations will be loaded based on the default culture set on the users PC.

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.110).aspx**